# Roblox ModuleScript reporting Infinite yield possible on

Tags: roblox

Helping my kid learn to develop.  Using Roblox as the tool.

We are in the ServerScriptService folder and in a file called OverheadRankScript. I have a line of code like this:

```
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local DataModule = require(ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("DataModule"))
```

My ModuleScript is in ReplicatedStorage folder and it is new and looks like this.

```
local module = {}

return module
```

I get the following error

> Infinite yield possible on
> 'ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("DataModule")'

I copied the example from this link
https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Scope

Does ModuleScript script need to be in Replicated Storage or is Server Script Service the correct area?
Not sure what I am doing wrong should the file name be DataModule or is ModuleScript ok?
Does the variable need to change not sure the example provided in the documentation does not seem to work.

Comment: The docs explain what's going on with your error: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/WaitForChild.
> If a call to this function exceeds 5 seconds without returning, and no timeOut parameter has been specified, a warning will be printed to the output that the thread may yield indefinitely; this warning takes the form Infinite yield possible on 'X:WaitForChild("Y")', where X is the parent name and Y is the child object name.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a warning, but you can add a timeout to it for the warning to stop showing up.

```
local DataModule = require(ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("DataModule", 10))
```

The 10 is the optional timeout parameter that you can change to whatever you'd like to.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what I found out was the DataModule needs to be renamed to ModuleScript. That Is the file name and it is referencing the file name.  The example referenced in the link does not mention this at all.  Infinite yield possible was misleading and it could not find the file.